# Create new Apps Script file with the Apps Script API - Error - Invalid JSON payload received

Tags: json, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-apps-script-api

I'm getting the error:

> Invalid JSON payload received

When trying to create a new Apps Script file with the Apps Script API.

How do I fix that error?

```
function createNewFile() {
  var d,options,payload,response,theAccessTkn,url;

  theAccessTkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  //See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create
  url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects";

  d = new Date().toString().slice(0,10);

  payload = {
    "title": "AA_" + d
  }

  options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  theAccessTkn
     },
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

  Logger.log(response)

  return response;
}
```

I have set the authorization scopes in the manifest file to avoid needing to add an OAuth library:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying `contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` in `headers`. [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: No, I'll try adding the `contentType`.  Thank you.

Comment: I added `"contentType": "application/json"` and it now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add `"contentType": "application/json"` to the options.

```
options = {
  "method" : "POST",
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "headers": {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  theAccessTkn
   },
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
};
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution... I momentarily forgot to `JSON.stringify` payload.